# Can't post formdata to app with webhook from automate.io

Tags: postman, webhooks

I have created an API that should return status 200
Please see  the postman request below.

However if I try to send the same post request trough automate.io I get status 400 back. Why is that?
Please see the automate.io below.

[image]

[image]